# Jquery's KeyboardJs add event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to make a webapplication that attaches a keyboard to an input (let the input's ID be input1). I want to trigger a function when the input changes (or the keyboard is clicked). So far I have tried

```
$('#input1').change(function(){
    doThis();
 });
```

and

```
$('#input1').on('change', function(){
    doThis();
});
```

However both does not call the *doThis()* function. Is there any way to create an event listener when a keyboard button is clicked? Thanks!

Comment: Are you changing value of input1? Also, is the above code inside document ready?

Comment: @nikhil - The keyboard will be changing the value of input1. However, I want it to also trigger another function while the user is "typing"...

Comment: You can use keydown event. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $("#input1").on("input", function() {
        console.log("Change to " + $(this).find("input").val());
 });
```

**Live link** : https://jsfiddle.net/dt10Lcqh/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    $(function(){$('#input1').keydown(function(event){
    //your code here
    alert($('#input1').val());
 });
 });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vikashvverma/jvqudj76/

Answer (score 0):

The on change event triggers once you focus out of the input element. Now, the question is whether you want to trigger the function on change that is once the user has done all the typing in the input field or for every word typed.

In case you want to call a function after all the typing is done - use **onchange event** else you can use **keyup event**.

Also, to make sure your binding is done, it is necessary to move your code in jQuery ready function.

So, update your code to the following for trigger event for every word typed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#input1').keyup(function(event){
        //your code here
     });

});
```

Here is a plunker as well for reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/cCwoiw6f8CaA1kfTVm6N?p=preview

I hope it helps!!